# Is it possible to merge the rows of a child table and display them in a query of the primary key table

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I'm working with three tables.  I can easily get the first output from the query below, but I'm looking to merge the authors into one field using COALESCE if its possible (see desired result).

[image]

tblPapers:
| PaperID | Title | PublishDate | Cost  |
|---------|-------|-------------|-------|
| 1       | T1    | 1/1/21      | $1.00 |
| 2       | T2    | 2/1/21      | $2.00 |
| 3       | T3    | 3/1/21      | $3.00 |
| 4       | T4    | 4/1/21      | $4.00 |
| 5       | T6    | 5/1/21      | $5.00 |

tblPaperAuthors:
| PaperAuthorsID | PaperID | AuthorID |
|----------------|---------|----------|
| 1              | 1       | 1        |
| 2              | 1       | 3        |
| 3              | 1       | 4        |
| 4              | 2       | 1        |
| 5              | 2       | 2        |

tblAuthors
| AuthorID | Author     |
|----------|------------|
| 1        | John Smith |
| 2        | Tom Book   |
| 3        | Jim Coast  |
| 4        | John Hanes |
| 5        | Dave Wait  |

1st attempt->   "SELECT tblPapers.PaperID, tblPapers.Title, tblPapers.PublishDate, tblPapers.Cost, tblAuthors.Name FROM            tblAuthors INNER JOIN tblPaperAuthors ON tblAuthors.AuthorID = tblPaperAuthors.AuthorID RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblPapers ON tblPaperAuthors.PaperID = tblPapers.PaperID WHERE (tblPapers.PaperID=1)"

Results ->
PaperID Title   PublishDate Cost    Author(s)
1   T1  1/1/21  $1.00   John Smith
1   T1  1/1/21  $1.00    Jim Coast
1   T1  1/1/21  $1.00   John Hanes

Desired result->
PaperID Title   PublishDate Cost    Author(s)
1   T1      1/1/21      $1.00   John Smith, Jim Coast, John Hanes

```
"DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX)
```

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + [Author]
FROM tblAuthors
SELECT @Names AS [List of All Names]"

Comment: Yes, the `LISTAGG()` function produces the result you want. The specific implementation will depend on the database engine you are using. Which db are you using?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please, no images. Use formatted text instead, so people can copy-and-paste.

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER (v18.9).  I will tag the post accordingly.  I tried the LISTAGG() function but it said it was not available.  I will add plain text for copying.

Comment: @JoelCooper 18.9 sounds like the version of SQL Server Management Studio, not the version of SQL Server. The SQL version will typically be displayed in the object explorer - eg: `... (SQL Server 13.0.4259.0 - ...)` - or as the result of a `SELECT @@VERSION` query.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)

Comment: I upgraded to SQL SERVER 2019 and the LISTAGG() function worked for me.  Thanks Impaler.